# Camera calibration using chessboard calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I am new to opencv . I am trying to calibrate my camera using this tutorial :

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d43/tutorial_camera_calibration_square_chess.html#gsc.tab=0

but i can not find the suggested folder with sample images. Furthermore, i cannot create the xml file. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you have a chessboard and a camera?

Comment: Yes i do. How many pictures should i take ? I think about 10 is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [this](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/stereo-calibration/) and [this](https://codeyarns.com/2014/09/01/how-to-calibrate-camera-using-chessboard/).
I did the calibration with 5 sec video (30fps).

[chessboard](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/_downloads/pattern.png)